# java.lang.stackoverflowerror: stack size 8mb while clearing focus of another edittext

Tags: android

Code causing the issue.

```
mPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override        
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {          
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (mOnlyMobileSignup) {
                mEmail.setError(getString(R.string.errorwrongmobile));       
                mPassword.clearFocus();
                return;          
             }
         }          
 });
```

Error caused by "mPassword.clearFocus();"

java.lang.stackoverflowerror

logcat:

```
        Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError stack size 8MB
        Raw Text android.text.SpanSet.init (SpanSet.java:46)
        android.view.View.clearFocus (View.java:5070)
        com.finwizard.fisdom.signup.SignInFragment$6.onFocusChange (SignInFragment.java:248)
        android.view.View.onFocusChanged (View.java:5207)
        android.view.View.clearFocus (View.j`enter code here`ava:5070)
        com.finwizard.fisdom.signup.SignInFragment$6.onFocusChange (SignInFragment.java:248)
        android.view.View.onFocusChanged (View.java:5207)
        android.view.View.clearFocus (View.java:5070)
```

Comment: post your code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: you do something that forces change focus on focus change recursively.